# What kinds of life would be found on a planet with little to no land or water?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, xenobiology

I am in the process of developing a world in which the only pockets of dry land consist of the peaks of mountains and clusters of floating islands. Each island has a lifespan of about 6000 years, after which it sinks back into the ground. They are constructed of hardened earth and rock with a top layer of seemingly fertile soil.

The chemical composition of the atmosphere is reminiscent of Earth, with the only exception being that the entire surface is covered with a poisonous fog (of an unknown chemical composition) that is four to five kilometres above sea level in thickness. Despite this, evaporation still occurs through the fog and clouds can form.

My question is, under these circumstances, what sort of life would evolve here? Would it even be possible? Please feel free to make any alterations to the information I have provided as you see fit.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a lot you need to clarify about the situation. What is "*futile soil*" and what does it mean to be "*seemingly futile*"? How do you have islands with no water? What are the "*floating islands*" floating in? A "*poisonous fog*"... poisonous to what? Without knowing what the fog is made of, we can't say what sort of life might survive in it.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don’t hqve land or water, what is there?

Comment: Answerers are not supposed to define their own constraints to questions. By stating "[p]lease feel free to make any alterations...", you are giving leave for answers to be entirely in reference to our real, existing Earth, and not about the world you want help in building.

Comment: Oh, "seemingly *fertile*". Ok... what makes it only "seemingly" fertile? Is it fertile or not? How can it be fertile with no organic matter or water? If this poisonous (again, poisonous to *what*) fog goes up 5km, does that mean the clear air is at an air pressure similar to 5km in Earth's atmosphere? That would make it pretty thin and puts it above any tree line really complicating things.

Answer (score 3):

**None**

6000 years is not enough time for life to evolve into a meaningfully complex form , and *definitely* not enough time for it to become multi-cellular. Also , it is unlikely that life would arise more than 3 separate times on a single planet , so it is very likely that this planet would be void of life. At best , even if life evolved separately on every island , the highest level of complexity would be that of Eubacteria. However , it would be possible to see unicellular organisms that develop spore phases and become airborne , spreading from island to island.

Also , you're question is fairly vague. What do you mean by "futile"? What mechanism makes the islands sink? What kind of planet is this on? We're pretty in the dark on this one.

Answer (score 1):

It is relative, what is a poison.

The biochemical processes of the life on this planet would evolve in a way, where this "poison" doesn't have any harmful effect to them.

Some similar already happened in the case of the Earth: for the first, anaerobic bacteria, oxygen was a *poison*, just as fluorine or chlorine for us. As the first plants appeared and started to fill the atmosphere with Oxygene, it resulted a larger ecological catastrophe as the extermination of the dinosaurs. See the [Great Oxygenation Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event).

Further, the life appeared first also in the Oceans of the Earth and existed there billions of year long. It didn't matter if any dry island exist, without them the life had been the same.

Although there is a suspection, that the life started initially at the beaches, these beaches would also exist in your world.

Thus, I think your world don't really differ from the ancient Earth and a nearly similar life would be created there.

---

On the longterm, it is very probably that continental life could only exist if they are capable to move between the islands as the part of their normal life cycle. I suspect animal life similar to the polar bears.

In the case of the plants, it is enough if they can seed through the wind.